# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli()

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estoy actualizando de PHP 5 a PHP 7 mi web y tengo problemas para que los menús desplegables que tengo en las paginas sigan teniendo conexión a la base de datos para presentar las opciones.

Instalé XAMPP para realizar las pruebas en modo local y conseguí solucionar varios errores, pero me quedé estancado en donde tiene que presentar las diferentes opciones del menú y después de hacer varios cambios no consigo dar con ello.

El error que me da es:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\menu.php:85 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TODOPOI\menu.php on line 85**

**El archivo original de conexión es conexion.php:**

```
<?php
function conectar()
{
    mysql_connect("localhost", "miusuario", "mipass");
    mysql_select_db("mibbdd");
}

function desconectar()
{
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

**El archivo final de conexion.php:**

```
<?php
function conectar()
{
    $comm = mysqli_connect("localhost", "miusuario", "mipass", "mibbdd");
}

function desconectar()
{
    mysqli_close();
}
?>
```

**El archivo original menu.php:**

```
<?php
function generaopciones()
{
    include 'conexion.php';
    conectar();
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    $consulta=mysql_query("SELECT enlace, opcion FROM select_radar ORDER BY id");
    // Voy imprimiendo los diferentes tipos disponibles en select_radar
    echo "<select name='.$selectDestino.' id='.$selectDestino.' onchange='if (this.value) window.location.href=(this.value)'>";
    while($registro=mysql_fetch_row($consulta))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$registro[0]."'>".$registro[1]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    desconectar();
}
?>

<div id="contenido" class="seleccion" style="height: 83px"><br><br><h3><strong>
            SELECCIONA TU MODELO<br><br><br></strong></h3>
        
            <div>   
            <?php generaopciones(); ?>
            </div>

            </div>
```

**El archivo final menu.php**

```
<?php
function generaopciones(mysqli $comm)
{
    include 'conexion.php';
    conectar();
    global $comm;
    mysqli_set_charset($comm, "utf8");
    $consulta=mysqli_query($comm, "SELECT enlace, opcion FROM select_radar ORDER BY id");
    // Voy imprimiendo los diferentes tipos disponibles en select_radar
    echo "<select name='.$selectDestino.' id='.$selectDestino.' onchange='if (this.value) window.location.href=(this.value)'>";
    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$registro[0]."'>".$registro[1]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    desconectar();
}
?>

<div id="contenido" class="seleccion" style="height: 83px"><br><br><h3><strong>
            SELECCIONA TU MODELO<br><br><br></strong></h3>
        
            <div>   
            <?php 
            global $comm;
            generaopciones (mysqli ($comm)); ?>
            </div>

            </div>
```

El error me lo da en esta linea:

```
generaopciones (mysqli ($comm)); ?>
```

Os agradecería vuestra ayuda para que la conexión la hiciese correctamente y me indicaseis si hay algún fallo más.

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que la conexión es correcta, veo que tienes un poco de lío en tu código.

Vamos a poner orden en todo esto:

1. En el archivo `conexion.php` es donde se crea la conexión, y eso ocurre dentro de una función llamada `conectar()`. Bien por ti, aunque no tan bién, porque sin un `return` no podrás en ningún caso sacar a la conexión del ámbito de la función. Eso por tanto es mejorable.
2. En el archivo `menu.php` tienes una función `generaopciones()` con un parámetro que sería la conexión. PERO luego dentro de la función haces un `include` del archivo que crea la conexión ¿? Si vas a acceder a la conexión desde dentro de la función no necesitas pasarla en parámetro. Creo que debes ver seriamente el tema de las funciones en PHP. Si tú declaras algo dentro de una función y lo necesitas fuera, debes poner un `return` dentro de la función y para obtenerlo debes llamar a la función que te retorna eso. ¿Queda claro eso?
3. Tu función `desconectar()` tiene el mismo problema, pero al revés. Para poder meter algo en el contexto de una función, debes ponerlo en parámetro y pasarlo cuando llames a la función. Significa que la conexión que quieres cerrar tienes que pasarla en parámetro. Aunque esa función lo único que hace es re-inventar la rueda, pues `mysqli_close` puede ser invocada *in situ*. Una función propia sólo tendría sentido si quisieras hacer más cosas aparte de cerrar la conexión. No parece ser el caso aquí.
4. Estás abusando de `global`. No es necesario para este caso, y sólo arroja confusión a tu código.

El código puede quedar así:

#### `conexion.php`

```
<?php
    function conectar()
    {
        $comm = mysqli_connect("localhost", "miusuario", "mipass", "mibbdd");
        #Trasladamos esto aquí, así no lo repites siempre
        mysqli_set_charset($comm, "utf8");
        #Si esto no podrás acceder de ningún modo la conexión
        return $comm;
    }

    /*
        mysqli_close necesita recibir en parámetro la conexión
        y la mejor forma de hacerlo es pasándola en 
        parámetro a tu función desconectar.
        Aunque es un poco tonto, porque puedes llamar
        directamente a mysqli_close in situ
    */
    function desconectar($comm)
    {
        mysqli_close($comm);
    }
?>
```

#### `menu.php`

```
<?php
    function generaopciones()
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        /*
           Dado que conectar() tiene un return
           puedes obtener en este ámbito la conexión
           asignando la variable al resultado de la llamada
           a conectar(). Esta es una práctica más recomendada
           que usar global
        */
        $comm=conectar();
        $consulta=mysqli_query($comm, "SELECT enlace, opcion FROM select_radar ORDER BY id");
        // Voy imprimiendo los diferentes tipos disponibles en select_radar
        echo "<select name='.$selectDestino.' id='.$selectDestino.' onchange='if (this.value) window.location.href=(this.value)'>";
        while($registro=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$registro[0]."'>".$registro[1]."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        /*
             Pasamos la conexión en parámetro para que desconecte...
             Aquí podrías pefectamente hacer esto:
             mysqli_close($comm);
        */

        desconectar($comm);
    }
    ?>
    
    <div id="contenido" class="seleccion" style="height: 83px"><br><br><h3><strong>
                SELECCIONA TU MODELO<br><br><br></strong></h3>
            
                <div>   
                <?php 
                /*
                    Ya no usamos global, ni falta que hace
                    Llamamos a generaopciones sin más,
                    pues todo ocurre dentro de la función
                    Me extraña que tengas esta llamada aquí 
                    y no al principo del archivo ¿?
                */
                generaopciones (); ?>
                </div>
    
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda @A.Cedano!! ahora si me aparece el listado de opciones en el menú desplegable, aunque me da dos errores de variable indefinida .$selectDestino en menu.php en esta linea:

```
echo "<select name='.$selectDestino.' id='.$selectDestino.' onchange='if (this.value) window.location.href=(this.value)'>";
```

Al pulsar sobre alguna de las opciones del menu, me dirige a la pagina de destino que tengo indicada en la BBDD, pero me da los siguientes errores en dicha pagina de destino y al pulsar sobre alguna de las opciones no me descarga el fichero al que apunta el enlace:

Notice: Undefined index: select on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: opcion on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: on line 9

Notice: Undefined variable: sql on line 14

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: selecc on line 30

Las 33 líneas de esta pagina de destino son:

```
<?php
function generaopciones()
{
    // Array que vincula los IDs de los selects declarados en el PHP con el nombre de la tabla donde se encuentra su contenido
    $listadoSelects=array(
    "citroen"=>"citroen"
    );
    $selectDestino=$_GET["select"]; $opcionSeleccionada=$_GET["opcion"];
    $tabla=$listadoSelects[$selectDestino];
    
    include '../conexion.php';
    $comm=conectar();
    $consulta=mysqli_query($comm, "SELECT enlace, opcion FROM citroen ORDER BY id");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    $id = "$row[id]"; 
    $opcion = "$row[opcion]";
    $enlace = "$row[enlace]"; 
    $descargas = "$row[descargas]";
    
    }
    // Voy imprimiendo opciones a elegir de copilot
    echo "<select name='select1' id='select1' onchange='if (this.value) window.location.href=(this.value)'>";
    
    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$registro[0]."'>".$registro[1]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    $sumador = mysqli_query($comm, "SELECT id, opcion FROM select1");
    mysqli_query($comm, "UPDATE citroen SET descargas=descargas+1 WHERE id = '$selecc'");
    desconectar($comm);
}
?>
```

Creo que solucionando esto lograría modificar las paginas de la web para que fuese compatible con PHP 7.4.26.

Si me pudieses ayudar con estos últimos errores abusando de tu amabilidad te estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Tu respuesta es en realidad otra pregunta, puedes generar una nueva pregunta o reformular la pregunta original si sigue siendo el mismo problema

Comment: Estos son nuevos problemas, con nuevas situaciones. Ten en cuenta que Stackoverflow no es un foro, funciona **por preguntas**, de modo que un caso pueda servir a futuros usuarios con un problema parecido. Te recomiendo que abras una nueva pregunta, planteando el nuevo problema o los nuevos problemas y que por otra parte des esta pregunta como resuelta marcando como aceptada la respuesta que te ayudó a resolver esta parte del problema. Si observas los títulos del sitio verás que esta área es para **respuestas**, no es para dar las gracias.

Comment: Los nuevos problemas que tienes son sencillos. Los *`Undefined variable`* ocurren cuando intentas usar variables que en  ese momento no existen. Si analizas el flujo de tu código podrás ver con facilidad que en un punto intentas usar esas variables sin haber sido declaradas todavía. En mi respuesta ya te hice un señalamiento sobre que tenías la llamada a la función en un lugar que me parecía extraño. Es cuestión de organizar mejor tu código.